# How can I have tablet devices access a standalone laptop web server?

Tags: networking, webserver, tablet, wampserver, wireless

I need to demonstrate a new website but in an environment with uncertain internet access. The site would be browsed by onsite visitors using tablet devices. My thinking was to create a copy of the site locally on a Windows 7 laptop running WAMP.

How do I create a proper connection between the laptop and the tablets so that users will be able to browse the site? I can run Bluetooth, for example, on the laptop but the trick is to enable web browsing rather than file sharing.

Thanks!

Paul Canniff

Answer (score 0):

If both devices are in the same network, you can simply find out the IP address of your laptop and enter this in the browser of your on your tablet, e.g. `http://192.168.0.2`.